# Magnesium in Cow's Milk

Tags: milk, labeling, magnesium

I have read online that cow's milk is a good source of Magnesium.

Example: http://abcnews.go.com/Health/13-foods-high-magnesium/story?id=30567212

However, the nutrition labels for various brands that I buy seem to never list Magnesium on the nutrition facts label.

Example: http://www.prairiefarmsdairy.com/index.php?p=453&i=693

Is the magnesium somehow lost in processing, or is the nutrition label simply incomplete, or what other reasons could explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is incomplete in a way. It's a rule by the FDA. [NIH](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Magnesium-HealthProfessional/):

> the FDA does not require food labels to list magnesium content unless
>   a food has been fortified with this nutrient.

So unless it's fortified you probs won't see it as the labels are filled with other things like Vitamin D, Calcium. And milk labels are quite small.

- [Milk is a good source of magnesium](http://milkfacts.info/Nutrition%20Facts/Nutritional%20Components.htm)